# Venn diagram visualization question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This my very first time working on Venn diagram. So please forgive me if its too naive/ or if the diagram is not suitable.

I am writing a conference paper and though a Venn diagram will make things more clear.

I have a directed graph structure $X.$ And a nice property $P$ that I wish $X$ to have. $X$ can be either cyclic or acyclic depends on its graph. Every acyclic $X$ has the property $P$. For cyclic ones, some satisfy P while others don't.

How to grasp this as a Venn diagram?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:
[image: Tikz Diagram]
Here is a minimal working example of how to create it via TikZ.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\P{(0,0) circle (3.5cm)}
\def\cyclic{ (-1,0) circle (2cm)}
\def\acyclic{(3.5,0) circle (2cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % fill \P and \cyclic
  \begin{scope}
    \fill[opacity=0.2,green] \P;
    \fill[opacity=0.5,green] \cyclic;
  \end{scope}
  % fill \acylcic
  \begin{scope}
    \fill[opacity=0.2,red] \acyclic;
  \end{scope}
  % fill the intersection of \acyclic with \P
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \P;
    \fill[opacity=0.5,green] \acyclic;
  \end{scope} 
  % draw the three circles and their labels
  \draw \P node [above = 2cm] {property $P$};
  \draw \cyclic node [below] {cyclic graphs};
  \draw \acyclic node [below] {acyclic graphs};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems you have mistaken cyclic with acyclic. I came up with the same diagram ( just replace acyclic with cyclic and vice versa). But I need to say that for all others that are not in the acyclic - the inner circle, they are indeed cyclic with property P.

Comment: @seteropere Oh, I indeed mixed them up. But I don't understand your last sentence. It seems like you don't like that there is an area in $P$ that is neither covered by cyclic or acyclic graphs. You could change that, but I'd advice against it - for the sake of aesthetics.